# close browser window javascript for blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, browser

I have close button in my JSP and onclick i want to close browser window.

I used window.close() but it act as history.back() in blackberry browser.
see  [this reference](http://docs.blackberry.com/de-de/developers/deliverables/11849/Window_close_569496_11.jsp).

I want to close window on click in BB.

Thanks

Comment: When you click on "CLOSE BUTTON" first remove all history items from the window and then call window.close() method;

Comment: Can't we close without clearing history?

Comment: Yes; We can't close without clean the history; It is problem in Blackberry; They are upgrading for next version;

Comment: As per my knowledge, we cannot remove history. We can just navigate through the history.
Is there any way that we can focus on last element of history object and write close() method on that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot. There is no way to do this :(
But we can try opening blank page or some url in the same window. This will make user feel that previous window is closed.